# python fuzzy package installation

Tags: python

So I am new (very new) to python (I have python32), and trying to install the fuzzy package to use Nysiis function. I've been googling installation procedure for pip and fuzzy package, but keep getting error as following:

File "setup.py", line 1, in 
from setuptool import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools

So from the error, I think setuptools have to be used to install, am I right? Also, do I need other packages to install the fuzzy package? Could someone take a step by step process of installing fuzzy package in python (from the beginning)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

pip is a good tool for getting python into your installation; it's built on top of setuptools and extends it to do its job.

It's sufficient to run the [pip installer](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) in your environtment; that will install pip and all of its dependencies (mainly setuptools).

From there, so long as the package is in the package index, you can run

```
pip install foo-package
```

If not, but a downloadable version is available which contains a proper `setup.py` (it sounds that way from your question), `cd` into the directory that contains the `setup.py` (usually at the top level) and run:

```
pip install -e .
```